# Emulating row_number in MySQL 5.7 with date condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in MySQL 5.7.34 and I have the following:

```
create table employees (
    employee_id int not null auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (employee_id)
    );
        
create table documents (
    document_id int not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(100) not null,
    last_modified datetime not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    primary key (document_id),
    foreign key (employee_id) references employees(employee_id)
);
```

I have created a [db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVuM5Vfa9Zo9r4uiUupvC4/0). The columns shown in the fiddle are only a few, but in the real data set, the `documents` table will have 20 or more columns and all need to show.

**SQL Query:**

```
-- simply query
select e.employee_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       d.title
from employees e
inner join documents d on e.employee_id = d.employee_id;
```

**Current Output:**

| employee_id | first_name | last_name | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | JD_Doc_Updated |
| 1 | John | Doe | JD_Doc |
| 2 | Mike | Anderson | MA_Doc |

**Desired Output:**

For each employee, I want to grab the most recent document only. In MS SQL Server (and recent versions of MySQL), I could use something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.employee_id ORDER BY d.last_modified DESC) AS num`

| employee_id | first_name | last_name | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | JD_Doc_Updated |
| 2 | Mike | Anderson | MA_Doc |

I am not sure how to achieve the same here.

I had a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql), and I don't think the problem here is the same, that other question deals with data on the *same table* and isn't dealing with `datetime` as the data type. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: Do you want only one column from the joined table? That would simplify things a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,
       d.title
from employees e join
     documents d
     on e.employee_id = d.employee_id
where d.last_modified = (select max(d2.last_modified)
                         from documents d2
                         where d2.employee_id = d.employee_id
                        );
```

For performance, you want an index on `documents(employee_id, last_modified)`.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVuM5Vfa9Zo9r4uiUupvC4/0) is a db-fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old MySQL version which doesn't feature window functions. So, to get the latest document per employee you need two steps:

1. get the maximum document ID or date
2. get the row belonging to that ID or date

Let's say "latest document" refers to the one that was last modified:

```
select *
from employees e
join documents d 
  on d.employee_id = e.employee_id
  and (d.employee_id, d.last_modified) in
  (
    select employee_id, max(last_modified)
    from documents
    group by employee_id
  )
order by e.employee_id;
```

The `IN` clause ensures that the joined document is in the set of latest documents. There are several other ways to write this. You can replace the `IN` clause with a correlated clause to refer to the employee's ID. Or you could join the tables and have a criteria that `NOT EXISTS` a newer document. Or you could upgrade to MySQL 8 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method. The first method is the same as `row-number` in MSSQL

```
select employee_id,first_name,last_name,title
from
(select *,
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @empl_no = employee_id 
          THEN 
              @row_number + 1
          ELSE 
               1
        END AS num,
    @empl_no := employee_id EmplNumber
from 
   (select e.employee_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       d.title
   from employees e
   inner join documents d on e.employee_id = d.employee_id
   order by d.last_modified desc) t1,(SELECT @empl_no :=0,@row_number:=0) as t2) T
where num = 1
order by employee_id
```

or  you can use `group by` then select max `last_modified`. finally join the `documents` and fetch title column.

```
 select t1.employee_id,t1.first_name,t1.last_name,title,t2.title
        from
           (select e.employee_id,
               
               max(e.first_name) as first_name,
               max(e.last_name) as last_name,
               max(d.last_modified ) as last_modified
           from employees e
           inner join documents d on e.employee_id = d.employee_id
           group by e.employee_id) t1
           
           join documents t2 on t1.last_modified = t2.last_modified
```